# How do I configure that way End users should be able to search the list items only by going to that specific list?

Tags: list, search, search-results

I do not want to display the list items on the search results for a specific list however End users should be able to search the list items only by going to that specific list - How do I configure this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can exclude the list from your search results in your Search Center either directly by editing the query or via a Result Source's query: **-path:http://MyIntanet/Lists/MyList***

This way users will still be able to search through that list with the included "Find a file/item" field.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to the List> List settings > Advance settings. You will have an option under search to "Allow items from this list to appear in search results". Set it to No. Run a full crawl.

Or you can create a crawl rule in the CA.
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219686.aspx

[image: Search]

Comment: Doesn't this also render the "Find a file" field above the list useless?